# Multiple Canvas Animations

Tags: jquery, css, animation, canvas

I have a fiddle of what I've achieved so far with Animating a Canvas.

http://jsfiddle.net/skerwin/uhVj6/6/

I'm trying to make a duplicate of the canvas, I want to change the amount it grows

Circle One:

```
var endPercent = 65;
var curPerc = 0;
```

Circle Two:

```
 var endPercent = 45;
 var curPerc = 0;
```

I'm really new to Jquery/Animations and Canvas. What do i have to do to duplicate the Animation code to make 2 Canvas' animate at the same time.?

Comment: Hey now.. you have a fiddle of what *I've* acheived so far :P http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692353/animate-a-canvas-circle-to-draw-on-load/15693230#15693230

Comment: I know. you greatly helped me. Majority of the work was done by you. noted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/dLAVe/
I wraped the code in a new `animate` function and changed the name of your `animate` function to `render`. The animate function now takes two arguments, the id of the element and the number of percentage.

Comment: Additionally you can change ´if (curPerc < endPercent)´ to ´if (curPerc <= endPercent)´ to make sure the 100% goes the full circle. Corrected version here: http://jsfiddle.net/dLAVe/1/

Comment: Absolutely Perfect. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

i think i like user1823799's answer better. but here is my solution to it. i basically added another `canvas` and `context` and in the same function i am checking for whether if the second arc reached its limit.

http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/6SuCC/

Comment: Your answer is still very good., user1823799 is more simple to understand (for a noob like me)

Comment: @Blackline i don't know much about canvas either. i am a noob too.