# jquery animation or gif?

Tags: jquery, animation, gif

I have 2 images and a map for "find the difference" game.

I want when I click on a difference an animation to show, like a hand drawn circle around the difference, but to be animated from start to finish.

I was thinking to do this with gif images with 1 loop, but I want to see if there is a better method.

Comment: Gif should be good instead of using many images with jquery

Comment: [This question and it's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692353/animate-a-canvas-circle-to-draw-on-load) may interest you. Take look at demo provided with the answer.